# Show $sin(\frac{x}{k})$ is uniform convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> For $k\geq 1$ we have the function $f_k : x \rightarrow
> > sin(\frac{x}{k})$. Show that $f_k \rightarrow 0$ uniform on $[-R,R]$
>   for every $R>0$.

To show it is uniform convergent I need to show there is some function $g$, such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} ||f_k-g||=0$.

My attempt was 
$$|f_k-g|=|sin(\frac{x}{k})-g| \leq  |\frac{x}{k}-g|$$ So if we take $g=\frac{x-1}{k}$, we get
$$=|\frac{1}{k}|$$
which goes to $0$ if $k$ goes to infinity.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, and if I'm even allowed to take $|sin(\frac{x}{k})-g| \leq  |\frac{x}{k}-g|$ this step, since we don't know anything about $x$.

Comment: The question already says that the limiting function is $0$ so why are you defining $g$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\sin (\frac x k)| \leq \frac {|x|} k \leq \frac R k$ which shows that $\sin (\frac x k)  \to 0$ uniformly.

[By MVT $|\sin t|=|\sin t-\sin 0|=|t| |\cos s|$ for some $s$ so $|\sin t| \leq |t|$].